# Trim by counting total number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a `VARCHAR2(210 CHAR)` field which has to be split into 6 lines of at most 35 characters split at the end of a word. Now for the below text I am getting 7 lines which should not happen. In this case I need to trim the text which goes to 7th line. Please help me with this.

Example:

```
WE REFER TO OUR PIN 103 QUOTED HERE
UNDER WHICH WAS SENT UNDER TRN 
QUOTED IN FIELD 20 AND PROCESSED 
UNDER YOUR REFERENCE IN FIELD 21 
BEST REGARDS PAYMENT INVESTIGATIONS
CENTRALIZED OPERATIONS CENTRE BOV 
MALTA.
```

The 7th  line text to be truncated.

Comment: What about selecting only `210` characters before splitting. You use `SUBSTR(COL,1,210)`  and then split the result into 6 rows

Comment: @Xing: Won't work. The text has 209 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cec55/18)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value VARCHAR2(210)
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
VALUES ( 'WE REFER TO OUR PIN 103 QUOTED HERE'
        || ' UNDER WHICH WAS SENT UNDER TRN'
        || ' QUOTED IN FIELD 20 AND PROCESSED'
        || ' UNDER YOUR REFERENCE IN FIELD 21'
        || ' BEST REGARDS PAYMENT INVESTIGATIONS'
        || ' CENTRALIZED OPERATIONS CENTRE BOV'
        || ' MALTA.' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           '(\S{0,35})\s*', -- Break any words longer than 35 characters
           '\1 '            -- and replace multiple white spaces with one space.
                            -- Will always leave a trailing space.
         ),
            '^(.{0,35})'    -- Up to 35 characters
         || '( (.{0,35}))?' -- Word break then up to 35 characters
         || '( (.{0,35}))?' -- Word break then up to 35 characters  
         || '( (.{0,35}))?' -- Word break then up to 35 characters
         || '( (.{0,35}))?' -- Word break then up to 35 characters
         || ' .*$',         -- Word break then rest of string to truncate (if any).
         '\1'
         || CHR(10) || '\3'
         || CHR(10) || '\5'
         || CHR(10) || '\7'
         || CHR(10) || '\9'
       ) As lines
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cec55/18/0)**:

```
|                               LINES |
|-------------------------------------|
| WE REFER TO OUR PIN 103 QUOTED HERE |
| UNDER WHICH WAS SENT UNDER TRN      |
| QUOTED IN FIELD 20 AND PROCESSED    |
| UNDER YOUR REFERENCE IN FIELD 21    |
| BEST REGARDS PAYMENT INVESTIGATIONS |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(
         TRIM( l.COLUMN_VALUE ),
         CHR(10)
       ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS lines
FROM   (
  SELECT ROWID As rid,
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           '(\S{0,35})\s*', -- Break any words longer than 35 characters
           '\1 '            -- and replace multiple white spaces with one space.
         ) AS value
  FROM   table_name
) t
CROSS JOIN
TABLE(
  CAST(
    MULTISET(
      SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '.{0,35} ', 1, LEVEL )
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.value, '.{0,35} ' )
             AND LEVEL <= 5 -- Number of lines
    ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
  )
) l
GROUP BY rid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cec55/18/1)**:

```
|                               LINES |
|-------------------------------------|
| WE REFER TO OUR PIN 103 QUOTED HERE |
| UNDER WHICH WAS SENT UNDER TRN      |
| QUOTED IN FIELD 20 AND PROCESSED    |
| UNDER YOUR REFERENCE IN FIELD 21    |
| BEST REGARDS PAYMENT INVESTIGATIONS |
```

Comment: In future if I need to change it to 4 or 5 or 6 lines, then which part of code I need to modify, can you please tell @MTO

Comment: Here what i  mean is full text should be there which is of 210 char fit into only 6 lines but not 7 lines. If it exceeds to 7th line then display the complete text only 6 lines or delete the text that goes into 7th line

Comment: @UshaSahithiReddy My first solution only works with 1-5 lines as you can only use single-digits in the references to capturing groups (so the maximum is `\9`). To reduce it to showing a maximum of 4 lines just delete the last `|| '( (.{0,35}))?'` line and the `|| CHR(10) || '\9'` line. I have also added another solution that will handle any number of lines.

Comment: @MTO For the query 1 which you gave is only restricted for 4 lines or can be extended to 6 lines. If it is extended then pls give me the solution. Thanks

Comment: @UshaSahithiReddy It can but you need to replace 4 lines (and include the remaining lines) and then wrap it in another regular expression which will match the previously replaced lines and then match lines 5-7 and format those and then repeat, wrapping in another regular expression, if you need more lines. It really does not scale well (but it is technically possible). The second query I have given you does scale.

Answer (score 0):

Done by a loop:

```
DECLARE
    src            VARCHAR2 (1000)
        := 'WE REFER TO OUR PIN 103 QUOTED HERE UNDER WHICH WAS SENT UNDER TRN QUOTED IN FIELD 20 AND PROCESSED UNDER YOUR REFERENCE IN FIELD 21 BEST REGARDS PAYMENT INVESTIGATIONS CENTRALIZED OPERATIONS CENTRE BOV MALTA. MALTA. MALTA. MALTA. MALTA. MALTA. MALTA. MALTA. MALTA.';
    target         VARCHAR2 (210);
    rowBuffer      VARCHAR2 (210);
    rowCount       INT := 0;

    maxRowLength   INT := 35;
    maxRowCount    INT := 6;
BEGIN
    -- Split text into words and loop through words
    FOR i IN (    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (src,
                                              '[^ ]+',
                                              1,
                                              LEVEL))
                             l
                    FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (src, ' ') + 1)
    LOOP
        -- Check if the current word can be added into rowbuffer
        IF (LENGTH (rowBuffer) + LENGTH (i.l) >= maxRowLength)
        THEN
            -- If row ist too long, add current row to target-string and start new buffer
            target := target || CHR (13) || CHR (10) || rowBuffer;
            rowBuffer := i.l;
            rowCount := rowCount + 1;
        ELSE
            -- enough room: add current word to rowBuffer
            rowBuffer := rowBuffer || ' ' || i.l;
        END IF;

        -- Let's have a look at our current row..
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rowBuffer);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('***********************************');

        IF (rowCount >= maxRowCount)
        THEN
            -- We stop if we got enough rows
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('We hit maxRows!');
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('************* RESULT  *************');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (target);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('***********************************');
END;
```

I admit: MTOs solution is much cooler ;). But in this solution you can configure rowlength and -count.